# Checkout git tags present on multiple branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-tag

I read a lot of SO posts but none of them make me understand how really work git tags especially concerning their link with branches. I think it is due to a misunderstanding of git principles. Maybe someone could help me.

Let's say I have the following two branches `master` and `develop` with `K` the merging commit:

```
-A-B-C-D-E-F-G-K-L-M (master)
       \-H-I-J-/     (develop)
```

If I tag the `J` commit, this tag will be on the two branches (because of the merge).
So when I `checkout` this tag, what version would I have? The one containing the `E`,`F`,`G` commits of the `master` branch or the one from the `develop` branch. Not sure I am clear about what I want to understand. I know that tags does not reference branch but only commit. But checkouting a tag also recover a commit historic doesn't it?

Comment: *"especially concerning their link with branches"* -- there is no such link.

Comment: *"Let's say I have the following two branches `master` and `develop`"* -- a branch is a pointer to a commit. You didn't show in the drawing what commits are pointed by the two branches.

Comment: Indeed, my drawing is not very clear but the first line will be my `master` branch and the second my `develop` branch

Comment: To be clearer, my question would be: if I checkout my tag, would I be in a state with the ABCDHIJ commits or with the ABCDEFGHIJ?

Comment: I guess you mean that `master` points to `M` and `develop` points to `J`. You should put this information in the drawing.

Comment: If you checkout tag at J, you would be in a state with ABCDHIJ commits.

Comment: Why do you say "If I tag the J commit, this tag will be on the two branches"? That is not correct.

Comment: So the state where the J commit was originally made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the position of the branches is like this (it does not matter very much, anyway):

```
                     v------- master
-A-B-C--D-E-F--G-K-L-M
      \-H-I-J-/
            ^------ develop
```

> If I tag the `J` commit, this tag will be on the two branches (because of the merge).

A tag is a read-only pointer to a commit. A branch also points to a commit but it is moved to another commit by many Git commands (`git commit`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, `git pull`, `git reset` being the most common).

Given the current position of the two branches, the `J` commit is reachable from both branches, indeed. `git commit`, `git merge` and `git pull` won't change this *status quo*. But `git reset` or `git rebase` can move the branch on commits that are not descendants of `J` and in such a situation `J` won't be reachable from the moved branch.

> So when I checkout this tag, what version would I have? The one containing the E,F,G commits of the `master` branch or the one from the `develop` branch.

`git checkout` changes your working copy to be identical to the checked out commit.

If you pass a branch to `git checkout` it also makes that branch the current branch (aka `HEAD`). If you pass to `git checkout` a reference that is not a branch (it can be a tag, a commit hash or other [revision specification](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) that resolves to a single commit) then you put the repository in a state that is named [*"detached `HEAD`"*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefdetachedHEADadetachedHEAD). This means there is no current branch.
Working in the *detached `HEAD`* state is not recommended (unless you know what you're doing) because the commits created this way are not pointed by any branch and are lost as soon as you checkout another branch (or tag or commit).

Assuming you run:

```
git tag tagJ J
```

to create the tag named `tagJ` on commit `J`, the following two commands do the same thing:

```
git checkout J
git checkout tagJ
```

They change the working tree and the index to match the status of the project recorded in commit `J`. They set the repo in the *detached `HEAD`* state.

The command:

```
git checkout develop
```

change the working tree and the index the same way as the two commands above. However, it doesn't set the repo to the *detached `HEAD`* state but set `develop` as `HEAD` (the current branch).

> But checkouting a tag also recover a commit historic doesn't it?

The history is determined by the branches and tags. Any commit that is reachable from any branch or tag is part of the history. If you delete the `master` branch f.e., the history of your repo will contain only the commits that are reachable from the `develop` branch (i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`, `H`, `I` and `J`). If you delete the `develop` branch (and keep the `master` branch) you don't loose anything because all the commits visible in the drawing are reachable from commit `M` (pointed by the `master` branch).

Comment: First, thanks you for this very detailed answer. I ask myself such a question because I would like to handle my releases thanks to git tags. I would like to be able to checkout the source code from a tag to build a release version. When we use GitHub and we create a tag, it allows us to download an archive. But I did not know what version was recovered, the one from `master` or the one from `develop`. If I well understood your answer, since the J commit is reachable from both branches, the GitHub archive will also contain `master` commits isn'it?

Comment: No. If you checkout `master` or `develop` the changes introduced by commit `J` will be included in the checked out working tree (if they are not undone by later commits, of course) because `J` is accessible from these branches. But if you checkout `J` then you will get only the changes introduced by the commits that are reachable starting from `J`. Commit *X* is reachable from commit *Y* if commit *X* is an ancestor of commit *Y*. If you checkout commit `J` then you'll get only the changes introduced by commits `A`, `B`, `C`, `H`, `I` and `J`...

Comment: ... You **will not** get the changes introduced by commits `D`, `F`, `G`, `K`, `L` and `M`.

Comment: The reachability works in only one direction: from children commits to their parent commits.

Comment: Ok so the state after the checkout of my tag will be the state of the branch `develop` because the commit was originally made in this branch?

Comment: It will be the state of the `J` commit (and a detached `HEAD`). Remember that the `develop` branch can be moved or deleted. You can make the `develop` branch point to commit `G` and this way it won't be related to commit `J` any more. The branches are only a handy way to refer to a commit and its history. They are not permanent. Commits and tags are permanent (to some extent).

Comment: It is clearer now. That's why there is no such link between git branches and tags, because some are temporary and other permanent. So to conclude, can I say that my tag will have the same state of the branch `develop` at the time of the commit J? (to understand clearly what modifications will be present on the checkout)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173398/discussion-between-axiac-and-alexandre-d).

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout a tag, but this will put your repository in detached HEAD state. Not on any branch, in essence.

See [Git Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Comment: So this state will not contain any of the modifications made in two branches ? That's what you mean?

Comment: Your local repository in this state will have any commits up until and including the tagged commit, so I guess yes.

Comment: Ok so when I download the archive of a tag from GitHub for exemple, will I recover the version of the `master` branch or of the `develop` one (where the commit was originally made)?

Comment: You tagged a specific commit, so it depends on how this commit was merged. I use Git Extensions as my Git tool and it visualizes all commits in the current state in a very clear way. You might want to look at that.